# Disable closing icon upon the slider's value

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to disable the closing icon upon the slider's value. Say when the slider has a positive value, then disable the closing function(red X icon). If not then to enable it.

What I thought was to set `WindowStyle` in the code.

C# code:

```
 public WindowStyle WindowStyle { get; set; }
 private void SliderValueChanged(object sender,
    RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        double value = slider.Value;
        if (value > 0.0)
          this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
        else
            this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow;
    }
```

XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="TestAsync.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     Closing="MainWindow_Closing"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow">
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Start" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="205,245,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <Slider Maximum="5000" TickPlacement="BottomRight" TickFrequency="100" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Name="slider" Margin="10,30,10,0" Height="30" ValueChanged="SliderValueChanged" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

But it is not working. Also there is a warning:

> 'TestAsync.MainWindow.WindowStyle' hides inherited member 'System.Windows.Window.WindowStyle'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

Comment: When you say it is not working, what do you mean? Does it crash, or just not do anything or...?

Comment: It means that the red icon is still there even the slider's value is greater than zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems here: First you've declared your own `WindowStyle` property, this property should be inherited from the Window. Secondly, your Slider should have some `Minimum` set to a negative value, so that user can slide it to some negative value. Otherwise, all he can do is slide it in range between `0` and the Maximum value:

```
//remove this
//public WindowStyle WindowStyle { get; set; }
```

and add some negative `Minimum` for the slider:

```
<Slider Maximum="5000" TickPlacement="BottomRight" TickFrequency="100" 
        IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Name="slider" Margin="10,30,10,0" Height="30" 
        ValueChanged="SliderValueChanged" Minimum="-100"/>
```

Now it should work.